# Oracle for computing transitive closure of presburger arithmetic formula if it exists: Computable?

Tags: logic, computability, presburger-arithmetic

Let $Q(\vec x, \vec y) \subseteq \mathbb Z^n \times \mathbb Z^n$ be a relation which can be represented in presburger arithmetic.

Let $R(\vec x, \vec y) \equiv Q \cup (Q \circ Q) \cup (Q \circ Q \circ Q) \dots\subseteq \mathbb Z^n \times \mathbb Z^n$ be the transitive closure of the relation $Q$.

We now ask for an oracle 
\begin{align*}
&O: \texttt{PresFormula} \to \texttt{PresFormula} \cup \{ \texttt{noformula}\}\\
&O(\texttt{presforumla}(Q)) = 
\begin{cases}
\texttt{presforumla}(R) & \text{if $R$ is expressible in presburger arithmetic} \\
\texttt{noformula} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

That is, the oracle $O$  on input the **presburger** forumla for $Q$, halts and returns the **presburger** formula for $R$ if such a formula exists. $O$ halts and returns a unique token $\texttt{noformula}$ if a presburger formula for $R$ does not exist.

What properties does $O$ have? is it computable? what is the complexity of this $O$ if it is computable? If it is uncomputable, are there weaker variants of this which is computable? I want something that's equal to $O$, and if this is not possible, the strongest possible oracle available.

I know that not all presburger arithmetic formulas have transitive closure that is not in presburger arithmetic: [Kelly and Pugh, 1996](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF03356760).

Comment: Wouldn't taking the transitive closure destroy information about the original relation? For example, let $R$ be a relation in presburger arithmetic that is distinct from its transitive closure $R^T$. The transitive closure of $R$ and $R^T$ is $R^T$. When $R^T$ is put through the oracle, it doesn't know which relation to output.

Comment: No, given input $R$ or $R^T$ the oracle would output $R^T$. I'm not asking for the inverse problem of finding the relation that creates the transitive closure. I want the oracle that creates the transitive closure given the relation.

Comment: Oh my god, I'm sorry, I mis-typed the question. Let me fix this!